# How to delete my app from internal release in play console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have my app in internal testing, I want to delete it because I have changed the package name and also I need to make some other changes to it like target age and some other stuff. I'm the only tester of the app that I have set before and it shows 1+ downloads in play store. Is there any way to delete the app from internal testing?
I want to create new one one from scratch and delete the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot remove any app from the listing from your Google Play Console like you delete any photo from gallery.
First you need to unpublish it and active installed zero.

To unpublish your app:

1. Open Play Console.
2. Select an app.
3. Go to Release > Setup > Advanced settings.
4. On the App Availability tab, select Unpublish.

Once done, you can contact support team for raise a ticket for further permanent removing of the app from your Google Play Console account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: From what I've read on message boards, it is very unlikely they will bother to permanently remove your app, even if it has zero active installs. It's hard to get a non-bot response from them at all--I don't think they are going to spend time on this since the only impact is to make the console less cluttered-looking for a single developer.